# angucomplete load data on focus by angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have a c# MVC project with Angular.js and entity framework.
In my view, I put an autocomplete with a controller
and it works properly.

I want to load dropdown data, when I focus in the textbox search of the autocomplete.

```js
        app.controller("HomeController", ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
            $scope.countries = [];
            $scope.SelectedCountries = null;
            $scope.AfterSelectedCoutries = function (selected) {
                if (selected) {
                    $scope.SelectedCountries = selected.originalObject;
                }
            }

            $http.get("/Home/Get_Doctor").then(function (d) {
                $scope.countries = d.data;
                $timeout(function () {
                    var searchInput = document.getElementById('txtautocomplete');
                    searchInput.focus();
                }, 0);
            }, function (error) {
                alert('Failed');
            })

        }])
```

```html
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Doctor</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <div ng-controller="HomeController">
                                        <div angucomplete-alt id="txtautocomplete"
                                             placeholder="Type Doctor name" pause="100"
                                             selected-object="AfterSelectedCoutries"
                                             local-data="countries" search-fields="Doctor_Name_Arabic"
                                             title-field="Doctor_Name_Arabic" minlength="1"
                                             input-class="form-control" match-class="highlight">
                                      
                                         </div>
```

Comment: So what's the question? What goes wrong? Any errors you see in console?

Comment: no errori want to know

Comment: no errors but i want to load dropdown data when i click in the search text box and focus in it what additional code can i use to do this